# Array issues I keep getting compilation errors

Tags: java, arrays

I'm currently working on some code but I'm having issues comparing two arrays, what am I missing?

```
package learn_Java_Fast;
//working on Arrays from Hello World

import java.*;

public class Arrays {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] arr1 = {0,2,4,6,8,10};
    int[] arr2 = {0,2,4,6,8,10};
    int[] arr3 = {10,8,6,4,2,0};

    boolean result1 = Arrays.equals( arr1, arr2);
    boolean result2 = Arrays.equals( arr1, arr3);

    System.out.println(result1);
    System.out.println(result2);
}
```

}

Answer (score 2):

Your class name `Arrays` clashes with `java.util.Arrays` - rename your class to any other name and your code will compile.

Comment: I had replaced Arrays with ArraysExample. I'm getting the same error.

Comment: package learn_Java_Fast;
    //working on Arrays from Hello World

    import java.util.*;

    public class ArraysExample {
     public static void main(String[] args) {
      int[] arr1 = {0,2,4,6,8,10};
      int[] arr2 = {0,2,4,6,8,10};
      int[] arr3 = {10,8,6,4,2,0};
  
      boolean result1 = ArraysExample.equals( arr1, arr2);
      boolean result2 = ArraysExample.equals( arr1, arr3);
  
      System.out.println(result1);
      System.out.println(result2);
     }
 

    }

Comment: I'm getting this error.  "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
 The method equals(Object) in the type Object is not applicable for the arguments (int[], int[])
 The method equals(Object) in the type Object is not applicable for the arguments (int[], int[])

 at learn_Java_Fast.ArraysExample.main(ArraysExample.java:12)"

Answer (score 0):

Try to import the Arrays class directly with a more precise package naming in case of overlaps.

Answer (score 0):

As Stepan pointed out, you have a name clash with java utility class, `Arrays`. You would be better served to rename your class. In addition, it is considered bad practice to import every single Java package through `import java.*;`. Instead, you can use `import java.util.*` to import the Java utility package.

Also, another poster incorrectly indicated that your array initialization is wrong; Your initialization via `int[] array = {1, 2, 3}` is in fact *correct!*

Comment: I had changed the name from Arrays to ExampleArrays. I'm still getting the same. I have the updated code and it's results posted under Stephens post. Thanks for your help!